# How can I make a SearchBox visible when I open the list of a ComboBox in Delphi

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey, search-box

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle to create multi device software (Win32) (Firemonkey).
How can I show a SearchBox only when the list is shown in a ComboBox.
I fill the ComboBox in code with ListBoxItems. See for an example below.
Now the SearchBox is displayed over a closed ComboBox.

```
procedure AddItems;
var
  SearchBox: TSearchBox;
  Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  ComboBox.Items.Clear;
  SearchBox := TSearchBox.Create(ComboBox);
  SearchBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Contents;
  SearchBox.Parent := ComboBox;
  SearchBox.Visible:=True;
  Item := TListBoxItem.Create(ComboBox);
  Item.Parent := ComboBox;
  Item.Text := 'Item 1';
  Item := TListBoxItem.Create(ComboBox);
  Item.Parent := ComboBox;
  Item.Text := 'Item 2';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TComboBox events `OnPopup` & `OnClosePopup`.

Move ScrollBox declaration to private form (or frame) section and create it in `OnCreate` form event (or in frame constructor).

```
type
  THeaderFooterForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSearchBox: TSearchBox;
  end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSearchBox := TSearchBox.Create(nil);
  FSearchBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Contents;
  FSearchBox.Parent := ComboBox;
  FSearchBox.Visible:=False;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.ComboBoxClosePopup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSearchBox.Visible:=False;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.ComboBoxPopup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSearchBox.Visible:=True;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you kami, but when I select the SearchBox for entering some text the list closes. The desired behaviour is to narrow down the items in the list.

Comment: my bad. I didn't think of that. You cant prevent closing popup window when SearchBox get focus (popup closed by `TScreen.ClosePopupForms`). Also, if you put SearchBox on the top of ComboBox.Popup it cant get focus for enter values...